# logback config not archiving on size constraint

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I am trying to add appenders to my spring boot application.

I have added the below configuration in my logback.xml file :

```
<appender name="application.log"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APP_LOG_ROOT}/application.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${APP_LOG_ROOT}/archivedLogs/info/application-%d-%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>
```

but still the file is not getting archived on reaching 100 mb
I have added the logging config in java args by ;
`-Dlogging.config=/etc/DemoService/logback.xml`

Please let me know if I am missing something

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing this `appender` through your `<root></root>`?:

Example:

```
<configuration scan="true">

   <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

    <File>${org.eclipse.m2e.log.dir}/0.log</File>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <FileNamePattern>${org.eclipse.m2e.log.dir}/%i.log</FileNamePattern>
      <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
      <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <MaxFileSize>100MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

  </appender>

        
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: No, I have not used any such thing